# $A.createComponent inline callback for ui:button.press

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Is is possible to create a "ui:button" and set "**press**" attribute to a **function** that's defined as a variable in the same scope of $A.createComponent, or **inline** which is the same, and NOT a function of the controller.

example:

**.cmp** content:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    {!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

**controller.js** content:

```
({

    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('doInit', component.getName(), component, event, helper);

        // already tried these 2, and errors on click
        // var inlineCallback = $A.getCallback(function() {
        //     console.log('pressed', arguments);
        // });
        // var inlineCallback = function() {
        //     console.log('pressed', arguments);
        // };

        var controls = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            var num = i + 1;
            controls.push([
                'ui:button',
                {
                    'aura:id': 'btn' + num,
                    'label': 'Button ' + num,

                    // how to use "inlineCallback"?
                    'press': component.getReference('c.buttonsPressed')
                }
            ]);
        }

        // create all
        $A.createComponents(
            controls,
            function (components, status, errorMessage) {
                console.log('created', arguments);
                component.set('v.body', components);
            }
        );

    },

    // all buttons
    buttonsPressed: function(component, event, helper) {
        var btn = event.getSource();
        var btnId = btn.getLocalId();
        console.log('button id `' + btnId + '` was clicked', btn);
    }

})
```

Comment: No that's unusual, whats the problem with defining the method in controer.

Comment: I'm currently studying components very deeply, and trying to figure out every possible way to create components and configure them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to use an inline function, you get an error like this:

> The provided key (function() { }) is not a string and cannot be used to look up values for the current component.

This error suggests that you always need to have a reference, because the function itself can't identify the correct component context to execute in. In other words, this is a security restriction to prevent code injection that might otherwise be possible.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could find the docs for this?

Comment: @MacA. Salesforce rarely documents things that you "can't" do. I'd be really surprised if any such documentation exists.

Comment: Just realized who you are, I greatly appreciate the time and effort you put into helping sfdc developers.

Comment: @MacA. Thanks! I just love helping people, especially on slightly off-the-wall questions like this that challenge me to learn something new or question why things work the way they do.